# pytest session not ending after completing all tests

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

I am trying to integrate pytests into my Jenkins project, but the Jenkins job is not able to finish because the test session for pytest is not ending.

Here is the simplest example I can come up with:

Python Test:

```
import pytest
import sys, time
sys.path.append('../../bindings/python')

class TestControl():
    def test_sanity_check(self):
        """
        Basic Test
        """
        assert (True)
```

Console Command & Output:

```
 python git:(ed25b33) ✗ sudo nano test_control.py 
➜  python git:(ed25b33) ✗ sudo python3 -m pytest -s test_control.py::TestControl::test_sanity_check
=============================================================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.4.3, pytest-3.3.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/examples/python, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test_control.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

============================================================================================================================ 1 passed in 0.67 seconds =============================================================================================================================
```

The test shows 100% completed, but for some reason is not terminating the session. I tried adding a sys.exit() inside the script but it results in an error. I just need the test to free up the console so my Jenkins work can finish.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had a setup_class but no teardown_class, and my class instance was still active, and preventing the test session from ending.